# make runs target even though file already exists

Tags: makefile, gnu-make

I have a Makefile like this

```bash
bin:
    mkdir -p bin

bin/kustomize: bin
    curl -fsSL "https://raw.githubusercontent.com/kubernetes-sigs/kustomize/master/hack/install_kustomize.sh" | bash -s bin
```

When I run `make bin/kustomize` it tries to download it, every time, even though it is already there. I would expect that make doesn't want to run that target.

When I remove the dependency to `bin`, it works as I expect.

Comment: Try replacing `bin/kustomize: bin` with `bin/kustomize: | bin`.

Comment: IMO easier than all that is to just delete the target for `bin` and add `mkdir bin` into the same rule that downloads the file.

Comment: @MadScientist, I have alot of stuff that goes into bin. I am trying to avoid that mkdir on all those.